# How To call stored procedure from linq to entities and get result into object

Tags: entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

i have one stored procedure,which returns string value.
now i have to call this stored procedure from linq to entity query,and store its result into 
my complex type's string property.
but i get the following error.
"cannot implicitly convert type objectresult to string".
my query has below:

```
using (NeoSoftWindowApp_dbEntities objDatabase = new NeoSoftWindowApp_dbEntities())
{
     ObjectParameter address = new ObjectParameter("Address", typeof(string));
     return (from tbl in objDatabase.COMPs
     select new CompanyReport_ComplexType
     {

    Address=objDatabase.ReturnAddressDetailForCompany(tbl.COMP_ADD1,tbl.COMP_ADD2,
                     tbl.COMP_ADD3, address),
        City = tbl.COMP_CITY,
        CompanyCode = tbl.COMP_NO,
        CompanyName = tbl.COMP_NAME

       }).ToList();
}
```

in above code ReturnAddressDetailForCompany() is my stored procedure which returns combine 
all 3 address value.
but i get error in c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call stored procedure in Linq-to-entity query because stored procedure is not composable (it cannot be used inside SQL select statement). You must use this:

```
 ObjectParameter address = new ObjectParameter("Address", typeof(string));
 return (from tbl in objDatabase.COMPs.ToList() // Here you change it to Linq-to-Objects
 select new CompanyReport_ComplexType
 {

Address=objDatabase.ReturnAddressDetailForCompany(tbl.COMP_ADD1,tbl.COMP_ADD2,
                 tbl.COMP_ADD3, address).FirstOrDefault(), // Here you must iterate result set from your SP
    City = tbl.COMP_CITY,
    CompanyCode = tbl.COMP_NO,
    CompanyName = tbl.COMP_NAME

 }).ToList();
```

but it will call stored procedure for every record in your result set (= it will make additional database roundtrip for every record).

Comment: what is the easy way of doing this to prevent extra additional roundtrip to database ?

Comment: You can't do that with SP. You must use database function instead.

Comment: Thank You sir for give me suggestion.